# Export Kendogrid data to excel in a generic way

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have configured the kendo grid and configured all the table rows and header.
When I click export button it is generating an excel file.But  it was showing the data format by opening in another URL with data:application/vnd.ms-excel,OrderIDFreight.......
I dont need to mention column names and like this export.
Button click for Export Grid data to Excel

```
var dataSource =  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource; 
 var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource( { 
     data: dataSource.data(), 
     filter: dataSource.filter() 
 }); 

 filteredDataSource.read();
  var data = filteredDataSource.view();

 var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";

  result += "<table><tr><th>OrderID</th><th>Freight</th><th>Order Date</th><th>Ship     
  Name</th><th>Ship City</th></tr>";


 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   result += "<tr>";

   result += "<td>";
    result += data[i].OrderID;
   result += "</td>";

   result += "<td>";
 result += data[i].Freight;
 result += "</td>";

 result += "<td>";
 result += kendo.format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", data[i].OrderDate);
 result += "</td>";

 result += "<td>";
 result += data[i].ShipName;
 result += "</td>";

 result += "<td>";
 result += data[i].ShipCity;
 result += "</td>";

 result += "</tr>";
 }

 result += "</table>";
 if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]),'export.xls');
 } else {
    window.open(result);
  }


 e.preventDefault(); 
 });
```

It should be in a generic way.

http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/100/

Thanks.

Comment: you mean column names and data should be exported in a generic way???

Comment: yes. Even if this is also fine. But this doesn't work in IE. So I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: i have seen some links which tells saveblob works for Ie10+   http://stuk.github.io/jszip/examples/download-zip-file.html

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle and check if it works in IE.

Comment: i am trying that, and with your code it's not working in ie 10 and below

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a server side export? This would work for sure & also gives you a provision to perform a full export rather than exporting the grid current page data.

Within the Kendo Code library, they already have a project that can help you do so. Kindly refer the link http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-grid-to-excel-8d91dd145501 for more details.